# Can't disable entry versioning

Tags: craft3, entry-versions, revisions

I've got a page with:

- 15+ sites (are used for serving different languages),
- a structure with matrix blocks and super table blocks inside them.

It took almost a minute to save an etnry, so I disabled versioning (even though it would be great to have it).

At a certain point I made an update (from something like `3.3` to `3.7.18.2` and `utils/repair/section-structure` in between) and revisions appeared again. I see a list of previously saved versions, saving is again slow.

Is it a bug or an expected behavior? I've got a feeling that I read something about it, and there's a config setting which does the job but after an hour of googling and checking the changelog I found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#maxrevisions

It shouldn't be slow. But it's best to limit the revisions, a good setting on a multisite is maximum 3 to 5 revisions, then you won't really feel the slowness.

Don't set it to 0, as that allows for unlimited revisions, the minimum you can have is 1.

Also upgrading to C4 is an option, as the performance of revisions have been increased tremendously!

Comment: Oh, it was so obvious! I though `maxrevisions=1` would still give me one additional revision.

Comment: But it's anyway slow with all the typed link fiels inside supertable blocks inside matrix blocks on 15 sites. Upgrade to 4.x will be done, but not soon, unfortunately.